# ROS2 node crashes abruptly

Tags: c++, ros-humble, ros-foxy

I have a legacy code in ROS1 that has the following code

```
ros::CallbackQueue cb_queue;
// some code

// inside a thread
while (nh.ok()) 
{
    cb_queue.callAvailable(duration);
}
```

Since it is a legacy code, I cannot rewrite completely. Thus, to retain the functionality abstraction while rewriting it in ROS2, it has been rewritten to

```
rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr cb_queue;
rclcpp::Executor::SharedPtr exe;

// some code 

// inside a thread
exe->add_callback_group(cb_queue, nh->get_node_base_interface()); // nh is of type rclcpp::Node
while (rclcpp::ok()) {
    exe->spin();
    rate.sleep();

}
```

When I run the node, I get the below error. I would like to learn when do we get following error? To ask it other way, if I am getting this error at runtime, what could be the reason?

```
rclcpp::QOSEventHandlerBase::is_ready(rcl_wait_set_s*) () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librclcpp.so
```

I am using ROS2 Humble Hawksbill. Since this is related to executors, I dont think ROS2 version should affect.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Please update your question by adding the details of the packages and commands you used. Also, mention specifically which version of ROS you are using. Currently, two versions are tagged. 
Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: @ravi Thank you, I have updated.

Comment: The issue can not be replicated due to the limited code provided. However, in your ROS 2 node, seeing `exe->spin();` inside `while` loop is concerning me. `exe->spin();` does not need a `while` loop. Please see an example [here](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/fac7da74281cbe6912e74aa78db633945b9ed930/rclcpp/executors/multithreaded_executor/multithreaded_executor.cpp#L174).

Comment: It is a static single threaded executor inside a thread. Not a multithreaded executor!